# Feliz Winter Bash 2018!

Tags: suporte

O mundo está repleto de tradições anuais interessantes. Vejam, por exemplo, os eventos de arremesso de [tomate](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomatina) e de [laranjas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Oranges), o [buffet para macacos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_Buffet_Festival), e as festividades da [corrida de queijos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corrida_do_Queijo). Com exemplos de criatividade humana como estes, nós no Stack Overflow não podíamos deixar passar esta oportunidade. Criámos e temos mantido a nossa própria tradição anual — o Winter Bash!

[image: Image of Winter Bash 2018]

Este ano estamos a tentar juntar os nossos utilizadores com a *malha* do nosso amor por chapéus, pelo sétimo ano consecutivo. E desta vez, até adicionámos uma maneira de poderem usar a vossa criatividade sem terem de desperdiçar fio real. Começando agora (12 de Dezembro de 2018) e até dia 1 de Janeiro de 2019 estamos oficialmente na [época do Winter Bash](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/)! Para ganhar estes chapéus especiais basta [completar desafios](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/) nos sites participantes. Estes desafios vão-vos dar a oportunidade de desbloquear chapéus que podem ser postos nos vossos avatares e usados pela rede fora. Este ano, modificámos a nossa seleção de chapéus e até adicionámos [algumas das vossas sugestões](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304500/a-moose-some-silly-putty-and-a-desperate-plea-for-help)! Alguns dos gatilhos para os chapéus também foram atualizados... e sim, há chapéus que vão querer descobrir por conta própria.

Quando completarem um desafio, vão reparar que um ícone com um chapéu vai aparecer no vosso perfil:

[image: Image of hat icon in profile]

Cliquem no chapéu e serão levados para a vossa caixa de chapéus:

[image: Image of hat rack]

Escolham um chapéu que tenham ganho e usem as ferramentas para modificar o seu tamanho e rodá-lo para caber no avatar:

[image: Image of resize tool]

E é isso! Agora podem exibir as vossas coleções de chapéus. Porque não usar um para cada dia da semana? É convosco - se o ganharam, podem usá-lo. No entanto, notem que no dia 2 de Janeiro todos os chapéus vão ser levados de volta para o armazenamento onde vão passar o ano todo a limpar e reparar os que se rasgaram ou sujaram.

Desejamo-vos muita sorte e alegria ao juntarem-se a nós mais uma vez para a nossa tradição anual.

Comment: Cada dia que passa eu gosto mais de estar por aqui. É a primeira vez que eu quero participar cem porcento das atividades de uma comunidade.

Comment: Quero muito conseguir esses chapéus, a duvida é eles vão ficar disponíveis mesmo depois do dia 2 ?